# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' some commands '

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

Is it possible to execute some sql commands within one EXECUTE IMMEDIATE block?

What is wrong with this syntax:

```
declare
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin           
    execute immediate
    'begin
        COMMENT ON TABLE t1 IS ''description1'';
        COMMENT ON TABLE t2 IS ''description2'';            
    end;';
end;
```

For one SQL command it works fine:

```
declare
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin           
    execute immediate ' COMMENT ON TABLE t1 IS ''description1'' ';
end;
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a single statement?

Comment: Executing in single statement will require less refactoring)

Comment: This is incorrect usage of "execute immediate" command. Understanding, that first statement is PL/SQL and the second is DDL helped me a lot. Thanks again, Shannon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `begin` `end` within the string to execute immediate is going to be treated as a PL/SQL anonymous block. DDL, such as `COMMENT` is not allowed in PL/SQL. If it were you wouldn't need to use execute immediate. Oracle essentially works with either a block of PL/SQL statement or a single SQL statement at a time. Though there are APIs to batch SQL statements too.

So, to run `COMMENT` within a PL/SQL block or procedure, you will need to `execute immediate` statements.

Without more context I can not intelligently comment on whether that is the right approach, or if just having the two comment statements stand alone would be better.

Comment: Thank you!If I understand correctly, there is no such a query to comment some tables within one execute immediate blok?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* do this:

```
begin           
    execute immediate
    'begin
        execute immediate ''COMMENT ON TABLE t1 IS ''''description1'''' '';
        execute immediate ''COMMENT ON TABLE t2 IS ''''description2'''' '';
    end;';
end;
```

But there's not much point.